# How should Bounded Contexts reference/use Generic Subdomains?

Tags: domain-driven-design

**1.** I can think of three ways **BCs** can use/reference *Generic Subdomains* ( **GS** ). Which way is most appropriate and why:

a - **BC** could have a reference to a *dll* within which **GS** is defined and as such this **BC** would be able to reference the types ( defined within the **GS** ) as needed ( **example**: a *method* defined in **BC** takes a *parameter* of type defined in **GS** )?

b – or should *entire* **GS** be defined within *Shared Kernel* ( this Shared Kernel would be shared with all **BCs** interested in this **GS** )?

c – or should only a *subset* of **GS** be created within *Shared Kernel*, while the remainder of **GS** would reside within a **BC**?

d – or is there a better alternative?

**2.** Is **GS** most often defined within a *single* **BC**?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Any domain (core, generic subdomain, supporting subdomain) should be in its own bounded context.

That being said, a generic subdomain is generic because it does not fulfill a specific business requirement.  It is, however, required to perform other business requirements.  So something like a calculation engine that can calculate tax rates, or policy premiums, or customer classification based on arbitrary arguments passed in would qualify.  It does not perform any business function.

I don't think a generic subdomain should be part of a shared kernel simply because it has no real business function.  A shared kernel, therefore, should encase a shared business model.

So a shared kernel would be used by more than one BC that performs specific business functionality.

I hope that helps?

Comment: 1 - "I don't think a generic subdomain should be part of a shared kernel" But why then does on page 355 Evans say that Shared Kernel could also be a GS? 2 - How should BCs use GSs? By having a reference to dll within which GS is defined ( as explained in a ) or ...?

Comment: This is just the way I approach these things.  Don't have the blue book anymore.  It is going to come down to how you want to define these terms for yourself.  Why have two terms that mean exactly the same thing? :)

Comment: "Why have two terms that mean exactly the same thing?" What terms are you talking about?

Comment: Shared Kernel and Generic Subdomain.  OK, maybe they don't mean the same thing :)